# show no result for default value of exposed filters

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-modules

I want to hide any results which are shown if filter is set to default value ,
is it possible to show no results or to make filter inactive if "-ANY-" is selected?
Or even better not to include this filter in searching result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go to advanced settings of the view and set exposed form settings to input required. Then you users will need to choose at least 1 value in filters to see view results.

Comment: But the default will show  results ,can i somehow exclude the output of default value of exposed filter?

Comment: Or is it possible to check if this field exists if -any- is selected

Answer (score 0):

I know its late, but for D7, here you have the settings inbuild.
http://drupal.org/node/358546#comment-7355100